# Webstorm svn changes in files

Tags: svn, netbeans, webstorm

Lately I changed to Webstorm from NetBeans and have small problem. I have my project checkouted to folder via tortoiseSVN. In NetBeans I was only opening files from checkout folder and I had labels which lanes changed/were added/deleted from last svn update. I guess that Webstorm has that feature too but probably needs some more configuration. Can someone point me out what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm does support this feature - see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-change-markers-to-view-and-navigate-through-changes-in-the-editor.html

Comment: Looks like what I need but in my project these markers do not appear. Do I need to connect Webstorm to repo and checkout via IDE?

Comment: yes, sure - these markers are only available when using WebStorm svn integration